# Complex Parse Query in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, parse-server, back4app

I have these Classes in parse db.

User ...

Post (user pointer<_User>  |  images Relation )

Image (post pointer  |  image File )

Follow ( user_from pointer  |  user_to pointer)

The questions are,

1- How to get the list of posts with their images of users who i am following. (in java android)

2- How to get a list of my posts.

3- How o get a list of my followers.

4- example of java class of User, Post, Image and Follow objects.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

probably you'll need to construct a relational queries, like the example below:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> innerQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Post");
innerQuery.whereExists("image");
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
query.whereEqualTo("postPointer", innerQuery);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(List<ParseObject> commentList, ParseException e) {
    // comments now contains the comments for posts without images.
  }
});
```

You can check more about it at Parse Docs